# Angular 1.5 Not able to clear the filter on ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using Angular 1.5 with Ionic version 1 and I have a view that displays the list of contacts, since there are several contacts so I am using a filter so the user can search for the contact.

This is my view

```
<ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Filter" ng-model="contactsFilter" id="search">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="contact in contacts |  orderBy: 'name.givenName' |  filter: contactsFilter track by contact.id "
            ng-click="create(contact)">
            <h2>{{contact.displayName }}</h2>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

As you can see `ng-repeat` is being used with a filter called `contactsFilter`.

What I am trying to do is clear the filter once someone clicks on an item so the entire list of contact is displayed again. I have tried the following solutions but none of them are working

```
$scope.create = function (contact) {
    delete $scope.contactsFilter;
    $scope.contactsFilter = '';
    $scope.contactsFilter = undefined;
    $scope.contactsFilter = null;
}
```

I will really appreciate if someone can let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: `$scope.contactsFilter = '';` or `$scope.contactsFilter = null;` should suffice, can you give a jsfiddle that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @devqon I am working on that

Comment: Works for mee, see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opbwxt08/)

Comment: @devqon this is so strange, i am looking into your fiddle

Comment: I removed all my code and replaced it with yours and that too is not working either, may be it has something to do with ionic framework, i am investigating it more

Comment: It indeed looks like an ionic issue, in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7D4r/47/)

Comment: thanks @devqon for having a look, hopefully i will find a work around of that

Comment: `$scope.create = function (contact) {` Which scope?

Comment: Hi @zeroflagL I am not sure if I understand your question

Comment: Which scope does `$scope` refer to? Where is `create` defined?

Comment: it is defined in the `view` on `ion-item`, `ng-click="create(contact)"`

Comment: there is a fiddle available if you want to play around with it http://jsfiddle.net/y7D4r/47/